# append items to ul element using JavaScript permanently

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I've got a few divs, and it's a dashboard kinda website so I need to update it everyday.
I can manually edit the HTML and all but that's you know...inefficient.

Each div has a `ul` element in it, and everyday I need to add a few `li` elements.

I've tried a JavaScript function that appends `li` elements and I'll add it in the code snippet too. But still, it's kinda temporary because if I delete that line of code in my js file the added `li` element will also disappear. So I'm looking for a way to append `li` elements to an unordered list permanently, and it would be nice to have a way to delete them too when they get really old.

```js
function append(ul, data) {
  try {
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).innerHTML = data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    console.log("error boi");
  }

}


append(document.getElementById("ul-1"), "door")
```

```css
div {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  div 1
  <br />
  <ul id="ul-1">
    <li>reeeeeeeee</li>
    <li>ramen ramen ramen ramen</li>
    <li>..........................</li>
    <!-- have to append few li items every day-->
  </ul>

</div>
<br>
<div id="2">
  div 2
  <br />
  <ul id="ul-2">
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ravioli ravioli ravioli ravioli</li>
    <li>..........................</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: To do this properly, you need a backend. You could use localStorage but you'll always risk losing all the data and it'll only exist in the one browser on the one device. Learn basic PHP and mySQL, install XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess u can use a JSON file to store and retrieve data, or u can go for PHP to get & retrieve data, yet u will be needing a Database, if I'm not wrong, using JSON would be more efficient.(If I'm wrong correct me)
check this link below [https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp#:~:text=JSON%20stands%20for%20JavaScript%20Object,describing%22%20and%20easy%20to%20understand](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp#:%7E:text=JSON%20stands%20for%20JavaScript%20Object,describing%22%20and%20easy%20to%20understand)
Hope this answer helped u.

Comment: thanks, this idea seems simple and easy so i'll try it out.

Answer (score 3):

#### Note ↓:

This piece of code just shows an example of how you can *add* or *remove* `items` easily from and to the lists!
As *@Chris G* and *@L.K. Kabilan* mentioned, to store data you either need a `Database` or in the `Local Storage`. However, by storing *data* in the `Local Storage` you're taking a risk of losing the data because it's stored **only** in the browser.

```js
// Get the elements
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

// Delete the item of the clicked 'X' icon
function delLi(){
    var del = document.querySelectorAll('li span');
    for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++){
        del[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.target.parentElement.remove();
        });
    }
}

// Get the selected option
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
});

// Wrap the input value in an item and append it to the selected list
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var val = input.value;
    if(val == '' || val.length <= 0){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
         var li = `<li><span>&times;</span><p>${val}</p></li>`;
        document.getElementById(selected).innerHTML += li;
        delLi();
    }
});

delLi();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
ul::before {
    content: attr(aria-label);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
li span {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(233, 208, 17);
    padding: 10px;
}
#input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-1">
        <ul id="ul-1" aria-label="List 1">
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 1</p></li>
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 2</p></li>
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 3</p></li>
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 4</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-2">
        <ul id="ul-2" aria-label="List 2">
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 1</p></li>
            <li><span>&times;</span><p>Item 2</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form action="">
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <select name="" id="select">
            <option value="ul-1">List 1</option>
            <option value="ul-2">List 2</option>
        </select>
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you :) i'll try everyone's answers and see how i can do it.